# Invoking Jython from Python (or Vice Versa)

Tags: python, jython

I'm working on a framework right now, part of which requires Jython. I just added some plotting to it using MatPlotLib, without realizing that MatPlotLib is incompatible with Jython. Since these two parts are pretty isolated, and I would be fine running most of the program in Python and passing a small amount of information to the Jython part (or vice versa), I was wondering if there's a simple way to do this, while maintaining the modular nature of the framework. Ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking execnet might not be a bad choice. Thoughts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not used [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet) for anything serious, but it seems quite possible that it is a good choice for you. execnet is a Python library for distributed execution across version, platform, and network barriers.

It is not hard to get started. This simple Jython script (that invokes NumPy) worked for me without a hitch:

```
import execnet

gw = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=python")
channel = gw.remote_exec("""
    from numpy import *
    a = array([2,3,4])
    channel.send(a.size)
""")

for item in channel:
    print item
```

Output:

```
3
```

The documentation [includes an example](http://codespeak.net/execnet/example/hybridpython.html#work-with-java-objects-from-cpython) that goes in the opposite direction (a CPython interpreter connecting to a Jython interpreter).

Comment: execnet is no longer actively developed. https://github.com/pytest-dev/execnet.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't use MatPlotLib with execnet ...

But ...

For a quick tryout with execnet (on a win32 platform) you can use [PortablePython2.7.2.1](http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython2.7.2.1)

PortablePython contains the MatPlotLib and is easy to install (and remove)