# How do I pass a list from python to jython return result to python

Tags: python, python-2.7, cgi, jython

I am running a python script from cgi-bin that needs to pass a list to jython so that it can use some library files do its thing then pass results back to python. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this task will be much appreciated.

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and jython 2.7.1. appreciate any assistance or response.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing. Beside that you seem to pass data from python ->jython -> jython which might need clarifying /correcting as your title suggests python > jython -> python..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to pass data between scripts. Most of them are independent from used programming language. Here are some examples:

1. Save result data to a file and read it by another script
2. Call another script with a result data as execution arguments (not recommended for a lot of data)
3. You can use stdin and stdout (piping) data from one script to another

Another solution can be implemented by the fact that Jython is basically compatible with CPython (the "reference" implementation of Python, written in C). There are some limitations, but you may consider / try to import your python scripts in jython. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085713/running-python-modules-in-python-from-jython) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727398/invoking-jython-from-python-or-vice-versa/9828977#9828977) you can read more about other methods.